# PostgreSQL: select all rows with a condition if it exists, else ignore the condition and select the earliest row

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have a PostgreSQL function `find_all_records_with_params()` that returns a `SETOF records`. The records table has the following columns:

```
table records(
id integer,
type integer,
created date,
content text
);
```

I would like to select all records where `current_date - created` is greater than 90 days. However, if this query does not exist, I would like to select 1 record with the earliest `created` date.

I tried to do this using a recursive cte (shown below), but it does not allow for if/else logic. I am trying to avoid calling the `find_all_records_with_params()` function twice and I do not wish to create a temp table, if possible.

```
with most_records as (select * from find_all_records_with_params()),
filtered_records as (select * from most_records where current_date - created > 90)
if exists(select * from filtered_records) then
select * from filtered_records;
else
select * from most_records order by created asc limit 1;
end if;
```

Comment: `current_date - created > 90` -- that's pretty ugly. Why not `created < current_date - 90`?

Comment: @DavidAldridge would there be a performance benefit doing `current_date - 90` over `current_date - created`? Does it cache that value?

Comment: It allows the optimizer to use an index, but furthermore it is much easier to read -- I've been writing SQL for 25 years but you put `current_date - created > 90` in front of me and I have to think hard about what that mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with most_records as (select * from find_all_records_with_params()),
filtered_records as (select * from most_records where current_date - created > 90)
select * from filtered_records
union 
select * from 
(select * from most_records 
where not exists (select * from filtered_records limit 1) 
order by created asc limit 1 ) a ;
```

I have used union query to achieve your required result. If your filtered_records returns result then query after union will not produce any result else query after union produces result.

Comment: thanks! what does the `limit 1` do when you do `where not exists (select * from filtered_records limit 1) `?

Comment: In where not exists (sub query limit 1)  , here  limit is used to reduce execution time. As we only need to check if there is record or not in filtered records.